# nav-tabs não fica visível em mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, componentes

Em monitor, funciona normal, mas em mobile a nav some. Pra testar e ver se não era alguma script que faltava no meu código, eu baixei um exemple do bootstrap com todos os links a css e js certinho, inseri o mesmo código, e funcionou no pc, mas no mobile sumiu também. Então claramente não é nenhuma dependência, mas porque a nav-tabs some em mobile e como consertar isso? Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light rounded">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample09">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active"  id="blog" href="#">Últimos Artigos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">História</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Geografia</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Economia</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" id="videos" href="#">Vídeos</a>
            </li>            
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search" placeholder="Pesquise um artigo...">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Procurar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas acho que vc deu uma "viajada" nas coisas. Vc colocou o Componente de **Navs**, dentro da **NavBar**! O.o Não tem como isso dar certo...

Veja que vc tem **TABs** dentro de uma **NavBar**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja na documentação que vc tem as **Navs** e as **Navbar**, são coisas distintas!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então se vc quer uma Navbar esses são os elementos e a documentação https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#supported-content
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Resumindo

Então vc não pode usar `<div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">` dentro de uma **Navbar** por isso não está dando certo ai

Comment: Isso nem chegou a ser descuido meu, eu realmente não sabia que teria essa reação na versão mobile, porque inserir o nav no navbar, no computador deu certo, no mobile ele sumiu. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Lucas então fica a dica ai. Inclusive salve esse link nos seus fávoritos, é muito importante consultar a documentação para esse tipo de coisa ;) Bons estudos

Answer (score 0):

Tem um pequeno equivoco ai, veja o exemplo abaixo, tem código faltando, coloque o conteudo dentro da:
''

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<div class="bd-example">
  <nav id="navbar-exemplo2" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#fat">@fat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#mdo">@mdo</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#um">um</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#dois">dois</a>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#tres">tres</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
  </nav>
  <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-exemplo2" data-offset="0" class="scrollspy-example">
<h4 id="fat">@fat</h4>
<p>Ad leggings keytar, brunch id art party dolor labore. Pitchfork yr enim lo-fi before they sold out qui. Tumblr farm-to-table bicycle rights whatever. Anim keffiyeh carles cardigan. Velit seitan mcsweeney's photo booth 3 wolf moon irure. Cosby sweater lomo jean shorts, williamsburg hoodie minim qui you probably haven't heard of them et cardigan trust fund culpa biodiesel wes anderson aesthetic. Nihil tattooed accusamus, cred irony biodiesel keffiyeh artisan ullamco consequat.</p>
<h4 id="mdo">@mdo</h4>
<p>Veniam marfa mustache skateboard, adipisicing fugiat velit pitchfork beard. Freegan beard aliqua cupidatat mcsweeney's vero. Cupidatat four loko nisi, ea helvetica nulla carles. Tattooed cosby sweater food truck, mcsweeney's quis non freegan vinyl. Lo-fi wes anderson +1 sartorial. Carles non aesthetic exercitation quis gentrify. Brooklyn adipisicing craft beer vice keytar deserunt.</p>
<h4 id="um">um</h4>
<p>Occaecat commodo aliqua delectus. Fap craft beer deserunt skateboard ea. Lomo bicycle rights adipisicing banh mi, velit ea sunt next level locavore single-origin coffee in magna veniam. High life id vinyl, echo park consequat quis aliquip banh mi pitchfork. Vero VHS est adipisicing. Consectetur nisi DIY minim messenger bag. Cred ex in, sustainable delectus consectetur fanny pack iphone.</p>
<h4 id="dois">dois</h4>
<p>In incididunt echo park, officia deserunt mcsweeney's proident master cleanse thundercats sapiente veniam. Excepteur VHS elit, proident shoreditch +1 biodiesel laborum craft beer. Single-origin coffee wayfarers irure four loko, cupidatat terry richardson master cleanse. Assumenda you probably haven't heard of them art party fanny pack, tattooed nulla cardigan tempor ad. Proident wolf nesciunt sartorial keffiyeh eu banh mi sustainable. Elit wolf voluptate, lo-fi ea portland before they sold out four loko. Locavore enim nostrud mlkshk brooklyn nesciunt.</p>
<h4 id="tres">três</h4>
<p>Ad leggings keytar, brunch id art party dolor labore. Pitchfork yr enim lo-fi before they sold out qui. Tumblr farm-to-table bicycle rights whatever. Anim keffiyeh carles cardigan. Velit seitan mcsweeney's photo booth 3 wolf moon irure. Cosby sweater lomo jean shorts, williamsburg hoodie minim qui you probably haven't heard of them et cardigan trust fund culpa biodiesel wes anderson aesthetic. Nihil tattooed accusamus, cred irony biodiesel keffiyeh artisan ullamco consequat.</p>
<p>Keytar twee blog, culpa messenger bag marfa whatever delectus food truck. Sapiente synth id assumenda. Locavore sed helvetica cliche irony, thundercats you probably haven't heard of them consequat hoodie gluten-free lo-fi fap aliquip. Labore elit placeat before they sold out, terry richardson proident brunch nesciunt quis cosby sweater pariatur keffiyeh ut helvetica artisan. Cardigan craft beer seitan readymade velit. VHS chambray laboris tempor veniam. Anim mollit minim commodo ullamco thundercats.
</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/scrollspy/#list-item-2

tem como mostra um de cada vez tambem